# How to Extract text from given string?

Tags: java

I want to extract a perticular image path string from a given string .

The String is `http:\localhost:9090\SpringMVC\images\integration-icon.png`

Now i want to get only the path after images like

```
\images\integration-icon.png
```

i tried this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("SpringMVC");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
System.out.println("Checking");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

how can i get ?

Comment: what is meant by **perticular**?

Comment: If you are using java 7 be aware of Path class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html

Comment: why you have given me -2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String string = "http:\localhost:9090\ZenoBusinessStore\images\integration-icon.png";
int index = string.indexOf("images\\");
String output = string.substring(index);
```

Comment: wont work, you'll get the error - Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ). Use escape sequences.

Comment: Are you sure? because I used a valid one

Comment: try and run it on a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

```
String filename = filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

or (haven't tried and looks somewhat odd)

```
String filename = filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf("\\", "images\\".length()) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "http:\localhost:9090\SpringMVC\images\integration-icon.png"
String subText = text.subString(text.indexOf("\images"), text.length());
System.out.println(subText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String in = "http:\\localhost:9090\\ZenoBusinessStore\\images\\integration-icon.png";
String op = in.replace("http:\\localhost:9090\\ZenoBusinessStore", "");
System.out.println(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ZenoBusinessStore` must be the name of your project which is constant.
Now split the string

```
String s = "http:\localhost:9090\ZenoBusinessStore\images\integration-icon.png";
String ary = s.split("ZenoBusinessStore");
```

Now the 2nd element of the array is your image path.

```
 System.out.println(ary[1]);
```

Comment: wont work, you'll get the error - Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ ). Use escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Use '\\'. It's because backslash is used in escape sequence like '\n'. With a single \ the compiler have no way to know.